# Double quotes in vim/ubuntu?

Tags: c, linux, vim

I apologize profusely for the incredibly newbish question I'm about to ask, but for some reason, my brain's locked up:

I'm trying to code in C on gvim on a virtual machine running Ubuntu, but my Hello World throws compiler errors which I suspect has to do with the quotes being different ascii(unicode?) codes than standard quotes.  It doesn't recognize "Hello World" as a string and says `"stray \250 in program" as well as "stray \302 in program"` each twice.

To type a double quote, I have to hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and double-tap the quote key.  This seems to be a global setting for all programs (terminal, open office, etc.)

Am I correct in assuming it's a problem with quotes, and if so, would any of you happen to know a solution to my problem?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you've got the wrong keyboard map set up. I got the same symptoms as you with a "UK (international with deadkeys)" keyboard map. Changed it to a standard UK one and it worked fine.

HTH

Rob

Comment: Thanks a lot!  Changing the keyboard layout and selected keyboard hardware seemed to do the trick.

Comment: Excellent. It bugged me for a couple of days at the weekend after a new ubuntu install!

Comment: Not sure how I got into the same mess but I had been struggling with this for a while.  Glad it was a simple fix.

Answer (score 0):

Isn't the double quote character (near the enter key) more appropriate?

Comment: that's the key I'm pressing.  when I press it once, nothing happens, but a double press makes a double quote appear.  If I'm not holding shift, double tapping it makes a single quote appear.

Answer (score 0):

I too had the same problem and the solution is just check what layout Ubuntu is using go into the settings and search keyboard and select region and language option and you will find the input source and just add English (US) one.